# How to check if a class is a Doctrine entity?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Given a class name, say `Domain\Model\User`, is there a programmatic way to know whether this class is marked as a Doctrine entity?

I could check for the presence of the `@Entity` annotation, but I'm looking for a generic way that would work with any metadata driver (annotations, YAML, XML, etc.)

Comment: Benjamin, do you mean whether or not the model in memory has been generated by Doctrine?

Comment: @Rottingham No, I mean whether the given class name is recognized as an entity by Doctrine, given the mapping information.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Courtesy [Stof on the doctrine-dev mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/doctrine-dev/3jQ4JFcJG-s/A3kHb7742G0J):

```php
return ! $em->getMetadataFactory()->isTransient($className);
```

I'll add that this method considers proxies (returned by the EntityManager as part of the lazy loading strategy) as transient; so if you're testing objects, don't blindly use `get_class()`, be sure to test first:

```php
$object instanceof \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Proxy
```

Working implementation:

```php
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Proxy;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

function isEntity(EntityManager $em, string|object $class): bool
{
    if (is_object($class)) {
        $class = ($class instanceof Proxy)
            ? get_parent_class($class)
            : get_class($class);
    }

    return ! $em->getMetadataFactory()->isTransient($class);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

As an addition to Benjamin his answer...
If you know for sure that you are handling doctrine entities, but you are not sure whether you have a proxy or a instance of the real class you can easily retrieve the real class by using the Doctrine Common `ClassUtils`:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Util\ClassUtils;
```

and then you can get the real class through the static `getClass` method like this:

```
$proxyOrEntity;

$className = ClassUtils::getClass($proxyOrEntity);
```

So this means @Benjamin his `isEntity` function can be written like this:

```
/**
 * @param EntityManager $em
 * @param string|object $class
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
function isEntity(EntityManager $em, $class)
{
    if(is_object($class)){
        $class = ClassUtils::getClass($class);
    }
    return ! $em->getMetadataFactory()->isTransient($class);
}
```

Which will give you true/false depending on whether the class is a doctrine entity or not.

Comment: Please note: `ClassUtils` has been depreciated as of Doctrine Common 2.9.

Comment: It has been undeprecated: https://github.com/doctrine/common/commit/f811639f788d3ce0bd152a983ac76a0aba42ff77

Answer (score 7):

One work around would be to test if you can generate a Repository. This is 'bullet proof' in that it will fail if the current schema and mapping does not know about the object class in question.

```
// Get the entity manager. I don't know how you do it
$em = new Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager();

try {
    $repo = $em->getRepository('YourClassModel');
} catch (Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException $e) {
    // NOPE! Not a mapped model
}
```

Comment: I came across a similar method with `$em->getClassMetadata`, and catching the `MappingException`, but am curious as to whether there is a slightly more elegant way... Let's wait and see!